# Point a arrow next to a specific table row

Tags: css

How can I point the arrow the 'here' row?

I have try putting it in a td tag but makes the row bigger.
https://jsfiddle.net/6vx6033y/

```
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: right;">test:</td>
         <td style=" text-align: left;">-$15.00</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: right;">test:</td>
        <td style=" text-align: left;">here</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: right;">test:</td>
        <td style=" text-align: left;">$15.00 </td>

    </tr>
    <div class="arrow">&#8601;</div>
  </table>
```

Comment: div.arrow cannot be child of table :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use a pseudo element: https://jsfiddle.net/6vx6033y/1/

```css
tr.arrow:after {
  content:'  \2199';
  position:absolute;
  font-size:1.5em;
  color:red
}
td {
  border:solid;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: right;">test</td>
         <td style=" text-align: left;">-$15.00</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: right;">test:</td>
        <td style=" text-align: left;">$0.00</td>
        
    </tr>
    <tr class="arrow">
        <td style=" text-align: right;">test:</td>
        <td style=" text-align: left;">$15.00 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: right;">tset:</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style=" text-align: left;">$15.00 <span class="arrow">&#8601</span></td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eceen7z4/

Answer (score 0):

you can play with `nth-child` properties, like that:

```css
.arrow2 TR:nth-child(2) TD:nth-child(2):after {
  color: red;
  content: "↙";
}
```

```html
<table class="arrow2">
    <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: right;">test:</td>
         <td style=" text-align: left;">-$15.00</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: right;">test:</td>
        <td style=" text-align: left;">here</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: right;">test:</td>
        <td style=" text-align: left;">$15.00 </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
```